# Connect to a VPN using command line and obtain specific ip address

Tags: vpn, pptp

I am using Windows 7 64bit and the [Rasdial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/ff859533(v=ws.11)) command in order to connect to a vpn pptp connection.

The command that I use is:

```
rasdial "connection" user pass
```

However, when I enter that command the IP is obtained automatically.

When I right click the connection settings I have the option to set manually IP address and DNS server.

I would likd to use the command prompt and specificy an IP address without manually editing the IP address at the GUI menu.

How do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: You talk to the admin that created the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address

One or more essential parameters were not entered.
Verify the required parameters, and reenter them.
The syntax supplied for this command is not valid. Check help for the correct syntax.

Usage: add address [name=]<string>
             [[address=]<IPv4 address>[/<integer> [[mask=]<IPv4 mask>]]
                  [[type=]unicast|anycast]]
             [[gateway=]<IPv4 address> [gwmetric=]<integer>]
             [[validlifetime=]<integer>|infinite]
             [[preferredlifetime=]<integer>|infinite]
             [[subinterface=]<string>]
             [[store=]active|persistent]
             [[skipassource=]true|false]
```